# Node.js & camaro - Influencing xml to json transform order

Tags: node.js, xml, csv

Node.js & camaro - Influencing xml to json transform order

I'm using node.js, camaro and json2csv to parse a xml file and convert it to csv. It seems to all work ... except ... I get a different output order as defined. I the template I defined the elements to be fetched ... and I was hoping to also output the values in this order. But it seems to be ramdon. How can I influence or get the right ouput order?

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse

const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597138973</responseData>
</httpSample>
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597139525</responseData>
</httpSample>
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597139716</responseData>
</httpSample>
</testResults>
`
const template = {
    data: ['//httpSample', {
        ts: '@ts',
        lb: '@lb',
        resp: 'responseData'
    }]
}

const result = transform(xml, template)
const csv = json2csv(result.data)

console.log(result);

{ data:
   [ { lb: 'req_10', resp: '1501597138973', ts: '1501597136964' },
     { lb: 'req_10', resp: '1501597139525', ts: '1501597136964' },
     { lb: 'req_10', resp: '1501597139716', ts: '1501597136964' } ] }   

console.log(csv)         
"lb","resp","ts"
"req_10","1501597138973","1501597136964"
"req_10","1501597139525","1501597136964"
"req_10","1501597139716","1501597136964"    

Desirerd order:
"ts","lb","resp"
```

... it seems that the output is always alphabetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed in v4.0.4 release https://github.com/tuananh/camaro/issues/69

PR: https://github.com/tuananh/camaro/pull/70